# In Rails, Search, index and edit all in the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I´m using Rails 3, and my default page setup will have:
1. A search form
2. A list with the results
3. A edit form, that will present the selected item from the list.

I don´t know how to do this without loosing my search params. Probably I have to pass my search params again when I select an item, but, how?

After all, what´s the best way to put all this in the same page ?

Comment: I don't understand your search params problem. Why do you need to keep search params after running a search?

Comment: This link covers retaining search params(and pagination/sorting if that interests you): http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Search form submits to `index` via AJAX. `index` sends down js.erb to load your partial. Selecting an item calls `edit` via AJAX. `edit` sends down js.erb to load your `edit` form. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without ajax, you can store search params in session:

```
session[:search_params] = "some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Still having problems when submitting the form to update action. No update action is called in the controller. I get this erro in log:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No
>   route matches "/cids"):

this is my main index page:

```
<div id="page-content">
  <%= render "search_form" %>
  <%= render "search_grid" %>
  <%= render "form" %>
</div>
```

this is the link to show edit form:

```
<td><%= link_to '', edit_cid_path(cid), :remote=>true %></td>
```

this is the edit.js.erb file:

```
$("#edit-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("form")) %>")
```

this is the begin of my _form partial:

```
<div id="edit-form">
  <% if @cid %>
    <%= form_for(@cid, :html => {:method => "put", :id=>"update-form"}) do |f| %>
      <% if @cid.errors.any? %>
```

and this is the application.js code:

```
  $("#edit-form").submit(function(){
    saveElement($(this).find("form"));
    return false;
  });

function saveElement(obj)
{
  $.post(obj.action, $(obj).serialize(),
    function(){refreshCss()},
    "script");
}
```

Comment: I found the problem in the code above, I have to specify the index of the find method:     saveElement($(this).find("form")[0]);